# How can I create such TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

Is there any way to get such TabLayout style? Or do I have to create my own custom view extended with TabLayout?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have to create you own custom view to do this.
Let me just warn you about that your need does not respects the material guidelines.